# React Js :Syntax Error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag

Tags: php, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I want to try an invoice app  tutorial on youtube. I got  errors that seem trivial but I don't see where the error is.

Error Message:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\ADS\Desktop\invoicerv2\invoicer\src\App.js: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <article>
```

Code

```
import React,{useState} from  "react";
import Table from "./components/Table";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Notes from "./components/Notes";
import MainDetails from "./components/MainDetails";
import ClientDetails from "./components/ClientDetails";
import Dates from "./components/Dates";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import TableForm from "./components/TableForm";

function App() {
//create a state value called show invoice and   
const[showInvoice,setShowInvoice]= useState(false)
const[name,setName]= useState("")
const[address,setAddress]= useState("")
const[email,setEmail]= useState("")
const[phone,setPhone]= useState("")
const[website,setWebsite]= useState("")
const[clientName,setClientName]= useState("")
const[clientAddress,setClientAddress]= useState("")
const[invoiceNumber,setInvoiceNumber]= useState("")
const[invoiceDate,setInvoiceDate]= useState("")
const[dueDate,setDueDate]= useState("")
const[notes,setNotes]= useState("")
const [description,setDescription]=useState("")
const [quantity,setQuantity]=useState("")
const [price,setPrice]=useState("")
const [amount,setAmount]=useState("")
const [list,setList]=useState([])

// calculate the total of amountfor the products 
const [total,setTotal]=useState(0)

// create a prop called handle print 
const handlePrint = () => {window.print()}

return (
 <>
  <main className="m-5 p-5 md:max-w-xl lg:max-w-2xl xl:max-w-4xl md:mx-auto  xl:max-w- 
   4xl  bg-white rounded shadow">
    {showInvoice ?  (
     <div>       
      {/* Header */}
       <Header handlePrint={handlePrint} />

      {/* Your details */}
       <MainDetails name={name} address={address} />

      {/* Client details */}
       <ClientDetails 
          clientName={clientName}
          clientAddress={clientAddress}/>

      {/* Dates */}
       <Dates 
          invoiceNumber={invoiceNumber} 
          invoiceDate={invoiceDate} 
          dueDate={dueDate}/>

      {/* Table  */}
       <Table 
          description={description}
          quantity={quantity}
          price={price}
          amount={amount}
          list={list}
          setList={setList}
          total={total}
          setTotal={setTotal} />

       <Notes notes={notes}/>

       <Footer 
          name={name}
          address={address} 
          website={website} 
          email={email}
          phone={phone} />

      <button onClick={()=> setShowInvoice(false)}
            className=" mt-5 bg-blue-500 text-white 
            font-bold py-2 px-8
            rounded shadow border-2 border-blue-500 
            hover:bg-transparent hover:text-blue-500
            transition-all duration-300">Edit Information</button>

    </div>):(
      <>
      {/* name, address,email,phone,bank name, bank account number, website,invoice 
    number,invoice date,due date,notes */}
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
      <article className="md:grid grid-cols-2 gap-10">
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="name"> Enter your name:</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="text " 
              id="name" 
              placeholder="Enter your name" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={name}
                onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}/> 
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="address">Enter your address:</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="address" 
              id="address" 
              placeholder="Enter your address" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={address}
              onChange={(e)=> setAddress(e.target.value)}/> 
        </div>
      </article>

      <article className="md:grid grid-cols-3 gap-10">   
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="email"> Enter your email:</label>
            <input 
              type="email" 
              name="email " 
              id="email" 
              placeholder="Enter your email" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="website">Enter your website:</label>
            <input 
              type="url" 
              name="website " 
              id="website" 
              placeholder="Enter your website" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={website}
              onChange={(e)=> setWebsite(e.target.value)}/> 
        </div>
            
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="phone"> Enter your phone:</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="phone " 
              id="phone" 
              placeholder="Enter your phone" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={phone}
              onChange={(e)=> setPhone(e.target.value)}/> 
        </div>
      </article>

      <article className="md:grid grid-cols-2 gap-10">
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="clientName"> Enter your  client's name:</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="clientName" 
              id="clientName" 
              placeholder="Enter your client's name" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={clientName}
              onChange={(e)=> setClientName(e.target.value)}/> 
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <label htmlFor="clientAddress"> Enter your  client's address:</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="clientAddress" 
              id="clientAddress" 
              placeholder="Enter your client's address" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={clientAddress}
              onChange={(e)=> setClientAddress(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>      
      </article>

      <article className="md:grid grid-cols-3 gap-10">    
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
          <label htmlFor="invoiceNumber"> Numero de Facture:</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="invoiceNumber " 
              id="invoiceNumber" 
              placeholder="Enter the invoice number" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={invoiceNumber}
              onChange={(e)=> setInvoiceNumber(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
          
        <div className='flex flex-col'>
          <label htmlFor="invoiceDate">Date</label>
            <input 
              type="date" 
              name="invoiceDate " 
              id="invoiceDate" 
              placeholder="Enter invoice date" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={invoiceDate}
              onChange={(e)=> setInvoiceDate(e.target.value)} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="dueDate">Date</label>
            <input 
              type="date" 
              name="dueDate " 
              id="invoiceDate" 
              placeholder="Enter invoice date" 
              autoComplete="off"
              value={invoiceDate}
              onChange={(e)=> setDueDate(e.target.value)} /></div>
        </div>
        {/*There I got the error  */} 
      </article>

     
       {/*This is our table form  */}
      <article>
        <TableForm
          description={decription} 
          setDescription={setDescription}
          quantity={quantity} 
          setQuantity={setQuantity}
          price={price}
          setPrice={setPrice} 
          amount={amount} 
          setAmount={setAmount}
          list={list}
          setList={setList}
          total={total}
          setTotal={setTotal}/>
     
        </article>

          <label htmlFor="notes">Additional Notes:</label>
            <textarea 
              name="notes" 
              id="notes"
              cols="30"
              rows="10"
              placeholder="Additional notes to the client"
              value={notes}
              onChange={(e)=> setNotes(e.target.value)}>
            </textarea> 

          <button onClick={()=> setShowInvoice(true)}
            className="bg-blue-500 text-white 
            font-bold py-2 px-8
            rounded shadow border-2 border-blue-500 
            hover:bg-transparent hover:text-blue-500
            transition-all duration-300">Preview Invoice</button>
    )
  </main>
</>
)
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some closing tag issue, check if this solves your problem

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Table from "./components/Table";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Notes from "./components/Notes";
import MainDetails from "./components/MainDetails";
import ClientDetails from "./components/ClientDetails";
import Dates from "./components/Dates";
import Header from "./components/Header";

function App() {
//create a state value called show invoice and   
    const [showInvoice, setShowInvoice] = useState(false)
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState("")
    const [website, setWebsite] = useState("")
    const [clientName, setClientName] = useState("")
    const [clientAddress, setClientAddress] = useState("")
    const [invoiceNumber, setInvoiceNumber] = useState("")
    const [invoiceDate, setInvoiceDate] = useState("")
    const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState("")
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState("")
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("")
    const [price, setPrice] = useState("")
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState("")
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

// calculate the total of amountfor the products 
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)

// create a prop called handle print 
    const handlePrint = () => {
        window.print()
    }

    return (
        <>
            <main className="m-5 p-5 md:max-w-xl lg:max-w-2xl xl:max-w-4xl md:mx-auto  xl:max-w- 
   4xl  bg-white rounded shadow">
                {showInvoice ?
                    <div>
                        {/* Header */}
                        <Header handlePrint={handlePrint}/>

                        {/* Your details */}
                        <MainDetails name={name} address={address}/>

                        {/* Client details */}
                        <ClientDetails
                            clientName={clientName}
                            clientAddress={clientAddress}/>

                        {/* Dates */}
                        <Dates
                            invoiceNumber={invoiceNumber}
                            invoiceDate={invoiceDate}
                            dueDate={dueDate}/>

                        {/* Table  */}
                        <Table
                            description={description}
                            quantity={quantity}
                            price={price}
                            amount={amount}
                            list={list}
                            setList={setList}
                            total={total}
                            setTotal={setTotal}/>

                        <Notes notes={notes}/>

                        <Footer
                            name={name}
                            address={address}
                            website={website}
                            email={email}
                            phone={phone}/>

                        <button onClick={() => setShowInvoice(false)}
                                className=" mt-5 bg-blue-500 text-white 
            font-bold py-2 px-8
            rounded shadow border-2 border-blue-500 
            hover:bg-transparent hover:text-blue-500
            transition-all duration-300">Edit Information
                        </button>

                    </div> :
                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
                        <article className="md:grid grid-cols-2 gap-10">
                            <div className="flex flex-col">
                                <label htmlFor="name"> Enter your name:</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="text "
                                    id="name"
                                    placeholder="Enter your name"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={name}
                                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="flex flex-col">
                                <label htmlFor="address">Enter your address:</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="address"
                                    id="address"
                                    placeholder="Enter your address"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={address}
                                    onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                        </article>

                        <article className="md:grid grid-cols-3 gap-10">
                            <div className="flex flex-col">
                                <label htmlFor="email"> Enter your email:</label>
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    name="email "
                                    id="email"
                                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="flex flex-col">
                                <label htmlFor="website">Enter your website:</label>
                                <input
                                    type="url"
                                    name="website "
                                    id="website"
                                    placeholder="Enter your website"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={website}
                                    onChange={(e) => setWebsite(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="flex flex-col">
                                <label htmlFor="phone"> Enter your phone:</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="phone "
                                    id="phone"
                                    placeholder="Enter your phone"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={phone}
                                    onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                        </article>

                        <article className="md:grid grid-cols-2 gap-10">
                            <div className="flex flex-col">
                                <label htmlFor="clientName"> Enter your client's name:</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="clientName"
                                    id="clientName"
                                    placeholder="Enter your client's name"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={clientName}
                                    onChange={(e) => setClientName(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="flex flex-col">
                                <label htmlFor="clientAddress"> Enter your client's address:</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="clientAddress"
                                    id="clientAddress"
                                    placeholder="Enter your client's address"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={clientAddress}
                                    onChange={(e) => setClientAddress(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>
                        </article>

                        <article className="md:grid grid-cols-3 gap-10">
                            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center">
                                <label htmlFor="invoiceNumber"> Numero de Facture:</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="invoiceNumber "
                                    id="invoiceNumber"
                                    placeholder="Enter the invoice number"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={invoiceNumber}
                                    onChange={(e) => setInvoiceNumber(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className='flex flex-col'>
                                <label htmlFor="invoiceDate">Date</label>
                                <input
                                    type="date"
                                    name="invoiceDate "
                                    id="invoiceDate"
                                    placeholder="Enter invoice date"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={invoiceDate}
                                    onChange={(e) => setInvoiceDate(e.target.value)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <label htmlFor="dueDate">Date</label>
                                <input
                                    type="date"
                                    name="dueDate "
                                    id="invoiceDate"
                                    placeholder="Enter invoice date"
                                    autoComplete="off"
                                    value={invoiceDate}
                                    onChange={(e) => setDueDate(e.target.value)}/></div>
                        </article>
                    <article>
                    <TableForm
                    designation={designation}
                    setDesignation={setDesignation}
                    quantity={quantity}
                    setQuantity={setQuantity}
                    price={price}
                    setPrice={setPrice}
                    amount={amount}
                    setAmount={setAmount}
                    list={list}
                    setList={setList}
                    total={total}
                    setTotal={setTotal}/>

                    </article>

                    <label htmlFor="notes">Additional Notes:</label>
                    <textarea
                    name="notes"
                    id="notes"
                    cols="30"
                    rows="10"
                    placeholder="Additional notes to the client"
                    value={notes}
                    onChange={(e)=> setNotes(e.target.value)}>
                    </textarea>

                    <button onClick={()=> setShowInvoice(true)}
                    className="bg-blue-500 text-white 
          font-bold py-2 px-8
          rounded shadow border-2 border-blue-500 
          hover:bg-transparent hover:text-blue-500
          transition-all duration-300">Preview Invoice</button>
                    </div>
                }
            </main>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```